# Please how can i use generate a formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

​

> df['weight_MA']=  (Pn ​  ∗W1 ​  )+(Pn−1 ​  ∗W2 ​  )+(Pn−2 ​  ∗W3 ​
> )... / ∑W ​

where:
P = Price for the period
`n` = The most recent period, `n-1` is the prior period,
and `n-2` is two periods prior
W = The assigned weight to each period, with the
highest weight going first and then descending linearly
based on the number of periods being used
​

Please how can i use that formula in pandas to get something like

> ((P5 * 5)+(P4 *4)+(P3 *3)+(P2 *2)+(P1 *1)) / (5+4+3+2+1)

Let’s say that the price of this stock fluctuates as so:

> Day 5: $90.90
>
> Day 4: $90.36
>
> Day 3: $90.28
>
> Day 2: $90.83
>
> Day 1: $90.91
>
> df['weight_MA'] = ((90.90 *5)+(90.36 *4)+(90.28 *3)+(90.83 *2)+(90.91 *1))
> / (5+4+3+2+1) =

Comment: Please provide dummy dataframe with expected output.

Comment: please i have adjust it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
weight = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
df = pandas.DataFrame([90.91,90.83,90.28,90.36,90.90])

df['weight_MA'] = df.rolling(weight.shape[0]).apply(lambda x: numpy.sum(x * weight) / numpy.sum(weight))
```

`rolling` gives you a dataframe consisting of the previous n row value. Then, applying a lambda function to multiply df and your weight, and divided by the sum of weight.